# Extracting values from a list to assign them as new variable in R

Tags: r, list, extract

I have a list which contains years, I want to extract one year from it and assigns its as a name of a data frame. For example I have a following list

```
a=[2000, 2001, 2003]
```

I want to call the value of a[1] so that I can assign the name of my data file as the of value of a[1], for example I want the following without directly calling '2000'

```
2000=read.csv(file1.csv)
```

Comment: `a[1] <- "file1.csv"`? Maybe you should make `a` a list instead, it might be easier to work with its names. It's unclear what you expect to happen with that code, though

Comment: You can't start an R object with a number, maybe consider calling your first data-frame `df2000` instead of `2000`

Comment: a[1] <- "file1.csv", will overwrite '2000' and assign a[1] as "file1.csv". I don't want that, I want to extract '2000' from the list "a" and name my file as '2000'

Answer (score 0):

The 'assign' function lets the value be assigned as a file name.

```
assign(as.character(a[1]), read.csv(file1.csv))
```

So one can run a loop to assign each year to it respective file